# How to select the count of values grouped by ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

Hail, Stack!

I need to select the count of values grouped by ranges.

To exemplify, suppose that I have the following values in a table columm: `1,2,4,5,6,8,9,11,13,16`

Then, I want to retreave the count of them in ranges of 5, like this:

```
From  0 to  4 there is 3 values (1,2,4)
From  5 to  9 there is 4 values (5,6,8,9)
From 10 to 14 there is 2 values (11,13)
From 15 to 19 there is 1 values (16)
```

And so on...

How can I make this in a query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT
    5 * (n div 5) as 'from',
    5 * (n div 5) + 4 as 'to',
    COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY n div 5;
```

For your sample this query gives you

```
+------+------+----------+
| from | to   | count(*) |
+------+------+----------+
|    0 |    4 |        3 |
|    5 |    9 |        4 |
|   10 |   14 |        2 |
|   15 |   19 |        1 |
+------+------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is basically Guffa's idea posted 8 minutes later.

Comment: @Andomar no it's not. MySQL (n / 5) returns a decimal, even if n is not a decimal. `div` required

Answer (score 3):

One way is the sum + case approach:

```
select  sum(case when col1 between 0 and 4 then 1 end)
,       sum(case when col1 between 5 and 9 then 1 end)
,       sum(case when col1 between 10 and 14 then 1 end)
...
from    YourTable
```

Another approach is to have a range table, filled like:

```
start    end
0        4
5        9
10       14
```

Then you can:

```
select  r.start
,       r.end
,       count(case when yt.col1 between r.start and r.end then 1 end)
from    YourTable yt
cross join
        RangeTable r
group by
        r.start
,       r.end
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculate a value that you can group on. In this case you just have to divide the value by 5 to get that result:

```
select value / 5 as Group, count(*) as Cnt
from TheTable
group by value / 5
```

This will give you are result like this:

```
Group  Cnt
0      3
1      4
2      2
3      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
val / 5 as grp,
case val / 5
when 0 then ' 0 to  5'
when 1 then ' 5 to 10'
when 2 then '10 to 15'
when 3 then '15 to 20'
end
as grpname,
count(distinct val) as cnt
from
(
select 1  as val
union select 2  
union select 4
union select 5
union select 6
union select 8
union select 9
union select 11
union select 13
union select 16
) a
group by 
val / 5
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for(i=MIN_OF_TABLE-1;i<=MAX_OF_TABLE;$i+=RANGE){
    SELECT COUNT(`VALUE`),GROUP_CONCAT(`VALUE`) FROM `TABLE` WHERE `VALUE`>i AND `VALUE`<=i+RANGE;
}
```

This will fetch rows containing the information you displayed in rows =)

Comment: I'm new to SQL data. is there a reason why this is not the best solution?