# A better way to execute a same SELECT query rather than inside a while loop thousands of time?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, query-optimization

I have a very inefficient query running hundreds/thousands times for different timestamp values that are generated inside a while loop. How can I take all the different values of $start_date and $start_date_interaval from the while loop?

I have tried to do subqueries, using IN clause as well as multiple WHEREs using OR but essentially it is the same as running queries individually. This is too slow, way too slow as the table contains a very large dataset. Im sure there is an easier way but not sure what.

```
while ($start_date <= $end_date) {

            $date_array[] = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($start_date));

            $start_date_interval = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date) + $interval);
            echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($start_date)) . ' ------> ';


            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalcalls FROM calls "
                    . "WHERE (use = 1 AND ((start_time >= '$start_date' AND start_time < '$start_date_interval') "
                    . "OR (start_time > '$start_date_past' AND start_time < '$start_date_interval' "
                    . "AND end_time >= '$start_date')));";


            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $data[] = $row['call_count'];
            echo $row["call_count"] . ' active calls.<br>';

            $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date) + $interval);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just select all the data in one go, sorted by `start_time`, and then handle the results accordingly within PHP?

Comment: Appreciate your answer, could you please provide me with a brief example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of distinct values to test against, 1 useful method is to have a temporary table loaded with all of the distinct values. You then join this temp table to select all of the rows you need.

If you can load the distinct value from the databases, it should have quite fast. If you have to upload a client dataset containing 1000's of values, there are [well-known techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql) to do this quickly. Search for others if you don't like these suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you ranges are fixed then you can group by ranges, create a query that will return the number of records for each range, maybe this post will help you:

[How to select the count of values grouped by ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136246/how-to-select-the-count-of-values-grouped-by-ranges)